# Pinescript - Simple Buy Sell Strategy not executing

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading, pine-script-v5

Hi i'm trying to write my first PineScript code for TradingView. Its a SMA crossover buy and sell strategy. The code seems to run without issue but no trades are found. Any feedback would be much appreciated

```
//@version=5
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true)

// Create Indicator's
shortSMA = ta.sma(close, 10)
longSMA = ta.sma(close, 30)


// Specify crossover conditions
longCondition = ta.crossover(shortSMA, longSMA)
sellCondition = ta.crossunder(shortSMA, longSMA)

// Execute trade if condition is True
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)
    strategy.close("long", when = sellCondition)


// Plot Moving Average's to chart
plot(shortSMA)
plot(longSMA, color=color.black)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling your `strategy.close()` if both `longCondition` and `sellCondition` are `true`.

Use another if check to close the position.

```
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)

if (sellCondition)
    strategy.close("long")
```